# crontab does not execute nor output send

Tags: permissions, cron, backup

I'm trying to run a script that archives a dir every day at 10 PM but It is not executed nor logs send. Please advise ..

```
[root@linux]# crontab -e 
0 5 * * 1 /usr/sbin/aide --check
0 22 * * * /root/backup/script.sh  >> /var/log/backup_crontab.log
```

Script :

```
[root@linux]# ls -lrt
total 2
-rw-r-----. 1 root root 1002 Sep 30 09:28 script.sh
[root@linux]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script isn't executable (-rw-r-----) where it should be -rwx-r-----).

just do a chmod u+x script.sh to add root execution rights.

except using `sh /root/backup/script.sh` running the script `/root/backup/script.sh` requires the script to be executable even from crontab.